# Which label I have selected

Tags: java, javafx

Im doing a work on javafx and I have to do a hexsodoku game.

I need to know which label I have selected so I can draw a red circle on it so that user may know it is selected.
Since I have waaay to many labels to do it one by one. How is it possible for me to know which one of the 16x16 labels is selected.

(i've though about doing a method that receives the selected lable but I dont know how to do it as well.)

Comment: By "selected" you mean "focused"? If not, how do you select the label. What exactly is your issue with the "method that receives the selected label" approach?

Comment: yes, i meant focused. the problem is that i have no clue how to do it xD

Comment: You should not use a Label for this. A label is meant to be a Control that you cannot interact with. If you try to set focus on a Label, what you really get is setting focus on he Control identified by the Label's labelFor field.

Comment: ah, right. so a textfield would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Labels aren't designed to be focused or selected. They're made as a way to display information to a user without user interaction.
You could look into using textfields, but then you'd have to restrict the user input to only 1 character or else it'll become bigger than the other textfields.

Comment: yes, I already changed it to have the textfields. Now I come back to the issue of the beggining . How can i know which of the textfields (inside a gridpane) is selected. is it possible to know?

Comment: @JoãoVieira I would have an "update" button of sorts. So the user can make their changes and then press "update". Another option would be to create a listener for each textfield (if that's even possible) and that way you'll know which textfield is being modified. But if you have 16x16 textfields, you're going to have a lot of listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CSS styling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region) to apply a style to an element when `:focused`.

```
.entry-field:focused {
    -fx-border-color: red;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-radius: 4;
}
```